# Python pandas data frame issue. How can I conditionally insert rows and get the subtotal of the numeric column? Already solved it but any improvement?

Tags: pandas

[image]
With the change of Function, I want empty rows inserted below and the subtotal of Amount in the empty row below.

How can I imporve the code? A better or shorter way?

```
insertROW_df = pd.read_clipboard()
insertROW_df

insertROW_df['match'] = insertROW_df['Function'].eq(insertROW_df['Function'].shift(-1))
insertROW_df['insert_row_below?'] = insertROW_df['match'].apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x == False else "No")
index_changed_row = insertROW_df.index[insertROW_df['match']==False]
type(insertROW_df)
line = pd.DataFrame({"Function": np.nan, "Budget": np.nan, "Amount":np.nan,"match":np.nan,"insert_row_below?":np.nan }, index=index_changed_row)
df = insertROW_df.append(line, ignore_index=False)
df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

df['Total'] = df.groupby(['Function'])['Amount'].transform('sum')
df['Total'] = df['Total'].fillna(method="ffill")

df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].fillna(df['Total'])

print(df)
print(df[['Function', 'Budget', 'Amount']])
df.to_excel(r'Z:\Claiming FY17, 18, 19, 20, 21 & 22\November 2021\Pythonic approach\InsertBlankRows.xlsx', index=False, header=True)
```

```
DATAFRAME = pd.DataFrame({'Function':['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC'],
                          'Budget': [550,550,550,680,550,550,550,860,860,],
                          'Amount': [14850,8640,2150,3210,5540,6660,2210,5555,5595,]
                          })
```

Comment: Will you please provide a text-based version of your data, e.g. a CSV or sample dataframe?

Comment: Please see the update to the post. I provided the dataframe. Sorry for the delay. Thanks,